# Two XML are same if they are refering to same XSD?

Tags: xsd

I am new to XML. I have two XMLs which are referring to same XSD. So can I assume that structure of both XMLs will always be same?

Comment: If both are valid against the same schema, then both fall into the class of XML documents accepted by that schema; whether that counts as having the same structure depends on the schema and on what you mean by "structure" and by "same".

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the XSD. It is possible for an XSD to be so lenient that the two XML files will be unrecognizable from each other. Eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema>
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Now your XML can technically contain anything and still be valid against the schema.

However, in general, if your parser is written correctly to conform to a specific XSD and you can validate the document against the XSD, then your parser will technically work with that XML document, you just can't make that assumption in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean "same structure".

Suppose, you have two programs written in Java:

- One program just prints "Hello world!" on the screen.
- Another program draws some complex fractal image (e.g. Mandelbrot set).

Do those programs have the same structure?
Of course they do! 
Because both are written in Java. The same Java compiler/Java machine can execute them
(no matter even on which hardware or OS)!
But here the similarity ends. These are very different programs, after all.

The same is with XML schemas.

Each XML schema effective defines yet another markup language -- an extension of XML
(also called **XML vocabulary**). That includes specific elements and attributes,
as well as various possible relations between them allowed in that language.

Note that **XML** is the acronym for **eXtensible Markup Language**, so XML schemas
actually do what the word "XML" literary says.

XSD (XML Schema Definition language) itself is that sort of language --
a special extension of XML. XSLT is another example.

So, do two XMLs that comply with the same XML schema have the same structure?
Yes, they do! They are written in the same XML vocabulary (like two Java programs).
That means, if you have some software that works with that particular XML vocabulary
and does something special about it, that software will be equally able to process both
your XMLs (no matter what they actually contain). The compliance with the same XML schema will ensure this!

But on this the similarity ends -- same as between two Java programs, which may be as different as an atom and a galaxy.